# PyScript: Loading from file failed with error 404 (File not Found) (Loading from another module)

Tags: python, html, pyenv, pyscript

How can I import from a local module from pyscript? This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
        <title>Title</title>
        <py-env>
        - paths:
            - ../app/db_operations/BookOperations.py
        </py-env>
    </head>
    <body>

        <py-script>
            from BookOperations import get_books_count
        </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to import the `BookOperations file` and the function `get_books_count` from it but I keep getting this error in the browser:

`PyScript: Loading from file ../app/db_operations/BookOperations.py failed with error 404 (File not Found). Are your filename and path are correct?`

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci7jv.png) is the image of my local project structure

This is what I've tried so far:

- write the path without the first dash `/`
  `(..app/db_operations/BookOperations.py)`
- using a single `.` at the
  beginning of the path `(./app/db_operations/BookOperations.py)`
- using no dots
- writing the path like "app.db_operations.BookOperations.py"
  (with `.` instead of `/`)
- moving the `py-env` tag inside `body` tag

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

Are you using a server program to serve your project? Something like VS Code's live server, or even [Python's included http server](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/257#issuecomment-1119595062) will work. If your files aren't made accessible on the network, PyScript running in the browser won't be able to fetch them.

PyScript has moved on quite a bit from the Alpha version - the latest release is [2022.12.1](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/releases/tag/2022.12.1) from mid-December. You'll find some increased functionality there; `py-env: paths` has been replaced with the much more flexible [fetch configurations](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-config.html?highlight=fetch#a-name-fetch-fetch-a) syntax  ([more info](https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2022-12-1/#paths)). Additionally, there are improved error messages for when fetching files fails that may be helpful.

Comment: This is a side project I'm doing, everything is local, I added my project path to the PYTHONPATH and all that so it should be visible. As for the new releases, I'm gonna check on them and maybe find the answer there. Thank you!

Comment: PyScript operating in the browser doesn't know about your PYTHONPATH - it only has access to packages that are available on the network. You can imagine how awful it would be if any arbitrary webpage was allowed to access the contents of your Python env, and PyScript is no different.

The way to make resources available on the network is to use a server program as I mentioned above. This is a common hiccup we see for those working with PyScript.